# Правильный порядок подключаемых скриптов

Tags: html, html5, javascript

Здравствуйте! Помогите пожалуйста расположить правильно скрипты, может что-то лишнее.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=TEMPLATE?>js/jquery.min7.js" ></script>         
        <script src="<?=TEMPLATE?>js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="<?=TEMPLATE?>js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?=TEMPLATE?>js/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="<?=TEMPLATE?>js/jquery.liSlidik.js"></script>                               
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?=TEMPLATE?>js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?=TEMPLATE?>js/workscripts.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?=TEMPLATE?>style/js/jquery.jcarousel.js"></script>
```

Одна функция работает только при jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js, а другая только при query-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js. Может что-то уже дублируется.

Comment: Отвечу по существу.. То что написано - это очень-очень плохо. Приучайтесь к хорошему стилю. Не надо из-за одного аккордеона целый UI тащить. Найдите другой, без привязки к UI.

Answer (score 1):

[[@Alextrue](/users/23784/alextrue)](/users/23784/alextrue), мощно вы, конечно, засадили.  Ничего не скажешь. ) Как шутят многие программисты - если работает, то не трожь. А вообще, берете и проверяете, берете и удаляете каждую библиотеку по очереди, если без нее фурычит, значит чудненько, если нет, то возвращаете на место, и так с каждой. )

Comment: @IamS, Не получается так, если продублируешь два раза ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js, то что-то начинает работать, тут все из-за версий 1.8.22 (без нее аккордеон не работает) - она для аккордеона, а 1.10.3 (с ней аккордеон не работает) - для отзывов.